# How to sync and merge local MySQL db with server MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, database

I have an app with a MySQL db running on a local network and I need to host it online. I need to work on the local version of the app on the local network and the server version outside the network.

I need the data to be consistent where the db is the same locally and on the server. Assume the same fields will not change on both (no merge conflict) and that sync and merge can take place once everyday - at the end of the day. Data may change on the local version, server version or both, that's why I need a merge. I've seen many other posts but couldn't find a clear solution.

How is that possible?

Comment: You're asking about many things here; in addition to data changing in a given table, there could be new constraints, triggers, etc.  What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: " I need to work on the local version of the app on the local network and the server version outside the network"...any particular reason you can't just have one central server? If you're concerned about security over the internet you could potentially connect via SSH, or put a Web API on the internet in between your local application and the database to serve requests over HTTPs and then only make database queries from the API to the DB. That would be a much more conventional architecture and remove this kind of awkward sync problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Only the data will change; ie some entries will be added to tables. No db structure or any of that sort will change. So I just want to merge the rows/entries between the local and remote databases and push it to both databases

Comment: @ADyson the thing is that the local network isn't always connected to the Internet and will not be always connected. This is a restriction. So once it connects at some time, sync and merge needs to be done.

Comment: But also updates can be made to the online database at another time? Is that from syncing by another site? P.S. Why will the local network not be connected sometimes? That's quite unusual. Is there no way around that? Also it's surely quite an assumption to state there will be no conflicts....can you guarantee it?

Comment: @ADyson yes true, the sync and merge needs to be done both ways, for example, everyday at 8pm run a script that fetches both databases, merges them, and pushes the final db to both... If the local network was always connected, I would have just kept the server version of the app and stopped the local app entirely. I personally don't know the reason, it is a requirement for a client.

Comment: what about the lack of any conflicts. Can you really be 100% certain of that? If there are never any conflicts, does the local DB even need to know about any updates from the server? Does it never read those records, or only never update them?

Comment: Yes there will be no conflicts since the user will either use the app on the server the entire day (when outside office) or the local version the entire day (when in office)..so a sync everyday shouldn't cause merge conflicts.. Yes db needs to know the updates so that the user can resume work when switching between versions

Comment: so there is only ever one single user? Do they have a laptop which they take with them when out of the office? It might be simpler to just run the database and application all on the laptop, and then back it up whenever it connects to the internet.

Comment: No, there are other users who have different privileges, they cannot modify what the previous user can modify, but they can view. They will be only working on the local version..It's quite complex, I have read about DB Replication and master slave but they all seem to give replication of 1 main db instead of using have 2 dbs as main dbs.. Thanks I appreciate your help

Comment: there is such a thing as mirroring but I think it requires the DBs to be clustered and I'm not sure how well it works with one DB being offline for long periods. They possibly also need to share a filesystem (e.g. via a SAN), although there may be a way round that.

Comment: These other users...they can't modify _anything_, or they can't modify things which other users can modify? Is there anyone who can modify everything?

Comment: Yes they can modify things that the main user mentioned above cannot modify. They will only do that locally. The main user needs to read the changes of the other users locally and on the server but not modify. Will read about mirroring

Comment: If you only have one user who can modify certain things, what happens if they are sick or unavailable and there's some urgent work needed? It doesn't sound very realistic to me. Sorry to ask so many questions and point out possible problems, I just want to make sure that this syncing really is the only possible option and that it's going to be feasible in  the long term. It's quite an unconventional scenario you've got.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is indeed an unconventional scenario, we decided that we will only allow one db to me modified - local one, and the server side app will be view only. then we can do db replication. Thanks for your follow up